# unkoown error [ Unknown JVM target version: 1.2 ]

Tags: flutter, dart

i don't know what was the error , it says

> Unknown JVM target version: 1.2
> Supported versions: 1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3GXT.png)

i don't konw where it's come from

i did try flutter clean , flutter pub get , flutter repair , cach clean etc....

nothing work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change jvmTarget to these versions 1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17

the bug on you'r android level gradle

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

Comment: what is jvmTarget ,

Comment: please go through this link : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98891